# call activity onCallStateChange from service

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I created `PhoneStateListener` in a `Service`. `Toast` messages work fine, but I want to run another `Activity` on incoming call. But it won't start. What is wrong with this class? Here's a code of main `Activity`, `DialogAct` is an empty `Activity` with layout.

```
public class GSMListenerService extends Service {
private TelephonyManager tm;

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
 }

 private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
     public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
         try {
             switch (state) {
             case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                 Intent i = new Intent(GSMListenerService.this,DialogAct.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 Toast.makeText(GSMListenerService.this, "CALL_STATE_RINGING: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 break;
             case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                 Toast.makeText(GSMListenerService.this, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;
             case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                 Toast.makeText(GSMListenerService.this, "CALL_STATE_IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;
             default:
                 Toast.makeText(GSMListenerService.this, "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.i("Default", "Unknown phone state=" + state);
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception", "PhoneStateListener() e = " + e);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) flag.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GSMListenerService.this, DialogAct.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Haven't you forgot to declare DialogAct activity in your manifest file? What is your logcat saying?

Comment: I declared DialogAct but i put incorrect path to the file, so you answer is correct, thanks!